# Place ImageButton in top left corner

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a very simple fragment layout (fragment_search.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.review.SearchFragment">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search_bar_button"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/switch_to_search_bar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_bar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

The fragment is hosted by activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My intention is for the `ImageButton` in fragment_search.xml to appear in the top-left corner with no gaps.  For some reason, when I run the app, the icon appears with a large gap above and a small gap to the left:

[image: Screenshot of app]

In Design view, the button appears in the top-left corner but with a 1mm gap between the button and the edge of the screen.

Why is the button not appearing in the top-left corner when I run the app, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove padding top from your activity root layout (contraintlayout) in activity_main.xml

> android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: Ah, should really have spotted that.  Thanks.  What about the small 1mm gap that still remains above and to the left of the button though; any idea why that's there?

Comment: @VorpulusLyphane it's from the button itself, there is little space. check this little experiment, look at the preview, also look at the third button, the little space won't be seen if the image is bigger than the button itself. https://imgur.com/a/tpiy2BM

Comment: Setting the background attribute also appears to remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, but I think it's because your activity layout not fragment layout, try to edit your activity layout and let me know what is the result.

or you can edit your question with showing activity layout where your fragments lies there.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying, but I have added the xml for activity_main.xml.  Does that help?